# PHP - Login sites externo

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados, login, libcurl

Estou a tentar criar um script que faça ligação a um site externo (tenho os dados de login necessários em base de dado MYSQL).

Gostaria de saber como posso fazer o login e preencher um formulário numa página especifica desse site.

Exemplo: `www.omeusite.com`

Quero ligar ao `www.site.com` e apos login automático com os dados enviados da base de dados preencher o formulário da pagina `www.site.com/formulario.php` e submeter o mesmo.

Comment: um jeito adequado de resolver isso é com API (webservice). Verifique se esse outro site oferece uma API. De outro modo, tudo que poderá fazer é gambiarras inseguras e instáveis

Comment: Obrigado, vou tentar encontrar essa API :)